# Installed numpy 1.8, but python still importing old 1.6.2 version

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I did sudo pip install numpy==1.8 to upgrade to the most recent version and it said the install was successful, but then I checked the numpy version again in the python shell and it's still importing 1.6.2. I went into the numpy directory at /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/ and it says the version is 1.6.2. I'm assuming that this is the version that came pre-installed. Where does the numpy upgrade get installed?

thnx

Comment: How have you installed pip?

Comment: yes, i have it installed

Comment: I'm asking how. Depending if it was installed using macports, homebrew etc the directory when it installs the files may be different.

Comment: To be honest I don't quite remember. It was a while back. It definitely wasn't macports though. What are you getting at?